# Marshalling a C++ Encoded String to C#

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to read in a structure that was written to a file by a C++ program (I don't have the source code).  I have been trying to read this structure into C# and marshal it so far without success.

The structure is basically a set of strings of fixed length, two-bytes per character.  In C++, they can be declared as TCHAR[8].

The data on disk looks like as follows:

[image: Data on disk]

I have tried the following C# code that I know can *successfully* read in the values as a string:

```
public void ReadTwoStringsOfFixedLength()
{ 
     string field1 = string.Empty;
     string field2 = string.Empty;
     FileReadString(handle, out field1, 16);
     FileReadString(handle, out field2, 16);
}

public static void FileReadString(BinaryReader reader, out string outVal, int length)
{
    var mem = new MemoryStream();
    outVal = string.Empty;

    byte b = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        b = reader.ReadByte();
        if (b != 0) mem.WriteByte(b);
    }
    outVal = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetString(mem.ToArray());
}
```

However, what I really would like to do is use c# structs, since this data is represented as a struct in C++ (and contains other fields which I have not depicted here).

I have tried various methods of attempting to marshal this data based on answers I have read on StackOverflow, but none have yielded the result I wanted.  In most cases, either the string encoding was incorrect, I ended up with a memory exception or I ended up with only the first character in each field (probably due to null-termination?)

Here is my code:

```
void Main()
{
   byte[] abBuffer = handle.ReadBytes(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(MyStruct)));
   //Access data
   GCHandle pinnedPacket = GCHandle.Alloc(abBuffer, GCHandleType.Pinned);
   var atTestStruct = (MyStruct)Marshal.PtrToStructure(pinnedPacket.AddrOfPinnedObject(), typeof(MyStruct));
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi), Serializable]
struct MyStruct
{
   [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 16)]
   string Field1   // Resulting value = "F"; 
   [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 16)]
   string Field2;  // Resulting value = "F" 
 }
```

Note that I have also attempted to use `CharSet.Unicode`, however the resulting strings are garbled.

Any help to fix the code would be much appreciated.

Comment: Could it be that the zero byte is being treated as a terminator rather than part of the UTF-16 encoding?

Comment: Some string tables in MFC used \0\0 as the string terminators / field separators for  2-byte characters.  Not really an answer to your question, just possibly helpful if you have any variable-length strings.

Comment: Hi @DrewNoakes, that does seem to be the case, I am just not sure what marshalling method I need to use to get around this (if it's possible).  Maybe the only workaround is to marshal as a byte array and convert?

Comment: Have you considered not marsheling the string? You could Pin the memory and then pass a pointer over to C#, and then construct a Span/Memory[char] over the array. Not exactly a string. But it will be silly fast.

Comment: Hi @Aron, do you have an example of what you mean?  It's preferable that I read the struct in one go if possible without having to convert a byte string.

Comment: In that case you are wanting to just marshal the strings over to .net as .net strings. Drew Noakes answer is closer to what you want.

Comment: Thanks.  I marked it as the answer.  I still need to test whether anything special needs to be done for Character encoding 1252 though.

Comment: Windows-1252 uses a single byte per character, so you will likely need `CharSet.Ansi`.

Comment: The only marshaling that works when reading this in (using the above-mentioned code) is `CharSet.Unicode`.  There was an edge case where "special" symbols such as the Pound symbol wasn't being decoded quite right unless I used `GetEncoding(1252)`.  I need to find the exact scenario again to see if this is still a problem when I used the provided solution of using `CharSet.Unicode`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to set `CharSet = CharSet.Unicode` on your `StructLayout`.

`46 00 69 00` in ASCII/ANSI is considered a single character and a null terminator. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.charset?view=netframework-4.8) shows that `CharSet.Unicode` is needed for two-byte characters, such as those you're showing.

The `SizeConst` value must also be the number of characters, not bytes.

Comment: Hi Drew, I think you are right!  Although could you please add the fact that I also need to reduce the halve the size of the "SizeConst" to 8 (i.e. number of characters as opposed to number of bytes).  This is what was causing the extra garbled data.  I will mark yours as the answer, thank you!

Comment: That is rather confusing, CharSet.Unicode maps to UTF16?

Comment: @aron there are many Unicode variants. The docs say `Unicode` means 2-byte characters, aka UTF-16, aka "16-bit Unicode Transformation Format": https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.charset?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: @Aron Microsoft documentation has a long "tradition" of calling *unicode* to what they should really be calling *UTF-16*. The real meaning of "Unicode" is much greater than that, and Microsoft always confuse the two in their docs. A legacy for being an early adopter I guess.

Comment: Keep in mind that Unicode was originally going to just be 2^16 characters, so UTF-16 was the natural fit... it wasn't until later that other planes (and surrogate pairs) were introduced. The name reflects that history, for better and for worse.